# Getting reCaptcha in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python module requests to send some requests to google but after some requests, a reCaptcha pops up.I am using user agent but it still pops up!

What should I do?

I used user agent, it did change the browser looks but it did no effect on the Captcha problem

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    sleep(2)
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
        'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
    }

    file = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=contact+email+{keyword}+site:{site}&num=100', headers=headers)
```

I used sleep but in vain. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s kind of the entire point of captchas. They help deter against bots and spammers. Most captchas can’t be bypassed easily, so just changing the user agent won’t make the captcha go away. Since it sounds like the captchas only appear after a certain number of requests, you could use rotating residential proxies and change the session’s IP address whenever a captcha is detected.

Alternatively, you can use a captcha solving service like [Anti-Captcha](https://anti-captcha.com/) or [DeathByCaptcha](https://deathbycaptcha.com/) which involves parsing information about the captcha and then sending it to a service that has workers manually complete it for you. It’s not exactly convenient or efficient, though, and it can often take up to ~30 seconds for a worker to complete a single captcha. Both options cost money.